# How to Move in and out of a Web page when Web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the URL that has all of the movies that start with the letter 'A'. i want to go into each movie, collect the data, go back and then iterate through the list until there are no more movies that start with the letter 'A' and then move on to the next web page where all the movies start with 'B' and so on until i get to the end of the alphabet. =  https://usa.newonnetflix.info/catalog/a2z/all/a

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://usa.newonnetflix.info/catalog/a2z/all/a')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

The below code is getting all the data i need from the url that is specific to each movie. So here i have clicked into a movie from the previous url and this is where i will scrape all the data i want. = https://usa.newonnetflix.info/info/70290905/s

```
title = soup.find_all('article',attrs={'class':'post infopage'})

for first in title: 
    movie = first.find('a')['title'].split(':')[0]
    category = first.find(attrs={'class':'genre'}).text
    rating = first.find(attrs={'class':'ratingsblock'}).text
    year = first.find('strong', text='Year:').next_sibling[1:]
    duration = first.find('strong', text='Duration:').next_sibling[1:]
    audio = first.find('strong', text='Audio:').next_sibling[1:]
    subtitles = first.find('strong', text='Subtitles:').next_sibling[1:]
    netflix = first.find_all(attrs={'class':'starrating'})[1]['title'][15:]
    imdb = first.find_all(attrs={'class':'starrating'})[7]['title'][12:]
    movieDB = first.find_all(attrs={'class':'starrating'})[13]['title'][26:]
    avgRating = first.find_all(attrs={'class':'starrating'})[19]['title'][15:]
```

I am unsure how to go into a new url and back out to the previous url to scrape the data for all movies.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the letters in the alphabet, form the proper url with each letter, and scrap the resulting contents:

```
import string
import requests, contextlib, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import namedtuple
film = namedtuple('film', ['title', 'tags', 'rating', 'extras', 'personel', 'ratings'])
def get_film_data(url):
   current_page = soup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
   title = [i for i in current_page.find_all('a') if 'title' in getattr(i, 'attrs', {})][0].text
   tags = current_page.find('div', {'class':'genre'}).text.split(', ')
   rating = current_page.find('span', {'class':'ratingsblock'}).text 
   data = [re.findall('[\w\W]+(?=:)|(?<=:\s)[\w\W]+', i.text) for i in current_page.find_all('p') if getattr(i, 'strong', None)][:7]
   new_data = [{a:b[0]} if b else {a:[i.text for i in current_page.find_all('p') if 'strong' not in i.attrs][6]} for a, *b in data] 
   director_and_cast = [[re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', i['href'])[0].capitalize(), i.text] for i in current_page.find_all('a') if re.findall('View all titles \w+', i.attrs.get('title', ''))]
   ratings = list(filter(lambda x:re.findall('\d', x), {i['title'] for i in current_page.find_all('img', {'class':'starrating'})}))
   return film(title, tags, rating, new_data, director_and_cast, ratings)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_page_films(page='a'):
  data = soup(requests.get('https://usa.newonnetflix.info/catalog/a2z/all/{}'.format(page)).text, 'html.parser')
  links = [i['href'] for i in data.find_all('a', {'class':'infopop'})]
  yield list(map(lambda x:get_film_data('https://usa.newonnetflix.info{}/s'.format(x)), links))

for i in string.ascii_lowercase:
  with get_page_films(i) as results:
    print(results)
```